# How to sum a Set[ValidatedNel[String, Double]]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have this:

```
Set[ValidatedNel[String, Double]]
```

and I would like to sum the Doubles in it to get:

```
ValidatedNel[String, Double]
```

If some elements in the values are then I would like to have matching strings.

I played with Set.sum and Numeric to no avail...

Here is the test of what I would like to achieve:

```
  test("Summing ValidatedNel works") {
    val val1: ValidatedNel[String, Double] = Valid(1.0)
    val val2: ValidatedNel[String, Double] = Valid(2.0)
    val values: Set[ValidatedNel[String, Double]] = Set(val1, val2)

    val validatedNelNumeric: Numeric[ValidatedNel[String, Double]] = ???
    val sum = values.sum(validatedNelNumeric)

    assert(sum == Valid(3.0))
  }
```

I don't manage to create the validatedNelNumeric...

Comment: How are you going to sum `Set(val1, val2, Invalid(List("a", "b").toNel, Invalid(List("c", "d").toNel)))`?

Comment: If instead of a **Set** you have a **List**, you can do `val sum: ValidatedNel[String, Double] = values.combineAll`. You would need to import `cats.instances.list._` and `cats.syntax.foldable._`. That, if and only if, you want to end with an invalid if there is at least one invalid in the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with: it feels a little weird to use a set in this case (for a collection of `Validated[..., Double]` values). What part of the `Set` semantics do you care about? The unorderedness? Uniqueness?

In general the most straightforward way to sum up elements that have a `Monoid` instance is to use the `combineAll` method for things with a `Foldable` instance—for example a `List` (but not `Set`).

```
import cats.data.{ Validated, ValidatedNel }
import cats.instances.double._, cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.foldable._
// or just import cats.implicits._

val val1: ValidatedNel[String, Double] = Validated.valid(1.0)
val val2: ValidatedNel[String, Double] = Validated.valid(2.0)
val bad1: ValidatedNel[String, Double] = Validated.invalidNel("foo")
val bad2: ValidatedNel[String, Double] = Validated.invalidNel("bar")

val values = Set(val1, val2)
val withSomeBadOnes = Set(val1, bad1, val2, bad2)
```

And then:

```
scala> values.toList.combineAll
res0: cats.data.ValidatedNel[String,Double] = Valid(3.0)

scala> withSomeBadOnes.toList.combineAll
res1: cats.data.ValidatedNel[String,Double] = Invalid(NonEmptyList(foo, bar))
```

I'm guessing that's what you mean by "If some elements in the values are then I would like to have matching strings"?

You could also use `SortedSet`, since Cats provides a `Foldable` instance for `SortedSet`, but it's not as convenient:

```
scala> import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

scala> import scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet

scala> (SortedSet.empty[ValidatedNel[String, Double]] ++ values).combineAll
res2: cats.data.ValidatedNel[String,Double] = Valid(3.0)

scala> (SortedSet.empty[ValidatedNel[String, Double]] ++ withSomeBadOnes).combineAll
res3: cats.data.ValidatedNel[String,Double] = Invalid(NonEmptyList(bar, foo))
```

You could also use the standard `fold` and the `|+|` operator for monoids:

```
scala> values.fold(Validated.valid(0.0))(_ |+| _)
res4: cats.data.ValidatedNel[String,Double] = Valid(3.0)
```

To sum up: you can't call `combineAll` directly on your `Set`, since Cats doesn't provide a `Foldable` for `Set`. I'd suggest carefully reconsidering your use of the `Set` in any case, but if you decide to stick with it, you have a few options: convert to `List` or `SortedSet` like I have above, use the standard `fold` on `Set`, or finally write your own `Foldable[Set]` or use the one from alleycats.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, I didn't minimize the imports. I'll do that later.

Comment: I can use a List, so all fine and it works :)

However in the end I would like to add something close to  case class MontantEnEur(montant: Double)

how to have ```combineAll``` work for user defined types?

I'm new to cats, sorry :$

Comment: Forget my previous comment, I found it: 


`
    implicit val montantEnEurAdditionMonoid: Monoid[MontantEnEur] = new Monoid[MontantEnEur] {
      def empty: MontantEnEur = MontantEnEur(0.0)
      def combine(x: MontantEnEur, y: MontantEnEur): MontantEnEur = MontantEnEur(x.montant + y.montant)
    }
`

Thanks again a lot :)

Side note: I don't manage to do empty lines in comments, sorry :$